# Using generators to wait for input before continuing the body of a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, yield, ecmascript-6

I just can't figure this out no matter how many generators articles I read...
I've also tried installing all the fibers libraries, and none of them will install on my machine, but that's okay, because I should probably learn how the native ES5 mechanism works, anyway.

This is what my code looks like so far..

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];

arr.forEach(function(n, i, arr){

    var rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout
    });

    rl.question('Enter input [' + [n, i].join(' ') + ']:', function(answer) {
          arr[i] = { prompt: [n, i], response: answer };
          rl.close();
    });

});
```

The problem is that the sequencing, predictably, goes like this:

```
Enter input [1 0]:
Enter input [2 1]:
Enter input [3 2]:

<input>
<input>
<input>
```

Whereas I need each output to be directly followed by its corresponding input.  How does one do this in generators and `yield`?

Thanks..

Comment: Just checking all I see is `Enter input [3 2]:` then the input is repeated three times.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `--harmony` `--use_strict` on the latest node (I tried on v0.11.9):

```
var readline = require('readline');
function* questionaire(arr) {
    for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        var n = arr[i];
        var rl = readline.createInterface({
          input: process.stdin,
          output: process.stdout
        });
        rl.question('Enter input [' + [n, i].join(' ') + ']:', function(answer) {
              arr[i] = { prompt: [n, i], response: answer };
              rl.close();
              console.log(arr);
              run.next();
        });
        yield n;
    }
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3];
var run = questionaire(arr);
run.next();
```